# How to use c++ templates to add pieces of code depending on a function parameter value?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, templates

Im doing some image functions, which have lots of repetitive code, such as:

```
int r,sr;
int g,sg;
int b,sb;
int a,sa;
...
for(...){
    sr += input[posin+0];
    sg += input[posin+1];
    sb += input[posin+2];
    sa += input[posin+3];
}
...
output[posout+0] = sr;
output[posout+1] = sg;
output[posout+2] = sb;
output[posout+3] = sa;
```

How can i use templates to do this from the above code:

```
int r,sr;
int g,sg;
int b,sb;
...
for(...){
    sr += input[posin+0];
    sg += input[posin+1];
    sb += input[posin+2];
}
...
output[posout+0] = sr;
output[posout+1] = sg;
output[posout+2] = sb;
```

or etc, depending on a value i give to the function? I could simply add if() in the loops, but that will slow down the function. So, i want  to cut parts of the code depending on the BytesPerPixel value i give to the function, how?

Also, the BytesPerPixel value should become a const inside the function, so if i use it somewhere and its value is 3, the calculation a*BytesPerPixel would become a*3. i want this to happen because it will make it faster, and multiplication with 4 or 2 or 1 will be even faster after compiler optimizes it.

Comment: You're asking to make compile time decisions at runtime.  I'll send you my DeLorean.

Comment: @Chad, im not? in a nutshell: i want to provide RGB, and RGBA (or 1 and 2 byte) image processing functions by writing just one template for them. i could do those by copypasteing lots of code, but that will be dirty.

Comment: You want certain code to not execute based on a parameter.  The only way to do that is with some kind of conditional (runtime).  To get a compile time difference, you would need two separate functions based on type.

Comment: @Chad technically he could use a template such as the `Int2Type` idiom and overloaded functions to make it a "compile-time if statement" but I don't believe that's any _cleaner_ than just using a function and profiling as James suggests below.

Comment: Indeed, but alas, that will still produce 2 different functions.  I think that James' suggestion is probably best.  I didn't really look close enough at the OP's code to see the refactoring he could do.  Although, I suppose its not really a solution to the OP's "general" question.  If his code was more complicated between the two different types, the below solution might not be applicable.

Comment: @chad, i dont care how many functions my code will produce, i only care about speed and clean code.

Comment: If you don't care about having multiple functions, then strongly type that bad boy and make 2 functions.  Then you're guaranteed to have the fastest code for each type.

Comment: @chad, and when i want to modify the function, i must modify 40 other functions as well..

Comment: Well, we've just gone full circle then haven't we?  You can't use templating to modify what binary runs unless you write separate functions for every type or use conditionals.

Answer (score 3):

Both of those can easily be reduced to:

```
int values[N];
// ...
for (...) {
    for (int i(0); i < N; ++i) {
        values[i] += input[posin + i];
    }
}

for (int i(0); i < N; ++i) {
    output[posout + i] = values[i];
}
```

`N` can be provided as a nontype template parameter; for example:

```
template <unsigned N>
void f() {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: +1 Beat me to it I was going to say you don't really need templates for this just make a function that simplifies it.

Comment: Well, using a template _may_ enable the compiler to unroll the loops in a way that yields better performance since it knows exactly how many iterations there are.

Comment: i know i can do it that way, but that will be a lot slower... i want to optimize speed here.

Comment: Have you tried this approach, profiled it, and determined that it is, in fact, a lot slower?  I would be very surprised if this was "a lot slower;" compilers are smart, you know.

Comment: hmm, in fact i havent, is it important to have `int i(0)` instead of `int i = 0;` ? also is it important to have `<unsigned N>` instead of `<int N>` ? would like to clarify those.

Comment: i couldnt make this work as i wanted, i tried to do `f<BPP>();` but it whines about stuff, so i tried to put it into a macro, but same thing, is the only way to use that method by making a switch statement for all possible values? will the compiler generate code for all the possible switch statements as well?

Comment: `BPP` (whatever that is) must be a compile-time constant.  A switch statement would be one way to delegate to the correct instantiation.  There is no difference between `int i(0);` and `int i = 0;`.  The difference between `unsigned N` and `int N` is that in the former, `N` is unsigned whereas in the latter `N` is signed.

Comment: OK, i profiled it now, and it doesnt seem to "unroll" the loops, i get 845ms with template and 784ms without template (7% diff), also interesting thing i found out that using `int rgb[3]` is faster than `int r,g,b;` which was a surprise to me.